# Intermittent Blazor Server-side Error: $ is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I am seeing an error in my logs that I am hoping to track down for my Blazor server-side application.  I have seen this in one way or another since deploying in February.  This seems to happen intermittently and I cannot seem to reproduce it in my own local development environment or in my testing, staging, and production environments.

In other words, this appears to be a rare, intermittent, but annoying issue.  I would like to fix it if possible.

This occurs in an `OnAfterRenderAsync` call, one which calls the `IJsRuntime.Invoke*Async` methods.  It will result in a message such as the following:

```
Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: window.$ is not a function
TypeError: window.$ is not a function
    at Module.NewDocumentElement (https://<site>/_content/DragonSpark.Presentation//Environment/Browser/Document/DocumentElement.js:11:43)
    at https://<site>/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:3501
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at kt.beginInvokeJSFromDotNet (https://<site>/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:3475)
    at https://<site>/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:72001
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at kt._invokeClientMethod (https://<site>/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:71987)
    at kt._processIncomingData (https://<site>/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:70029)
    at vt.connection.onreceive (https://<site>/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:64432)
    at WebSocket.o.onmessage (https://<site>/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:48766)
   at async ValueTask<TValue> Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<TValue>(long targetInstanceId, string identifier, object[] args)
   at async ValueTask<TOut> DragonSpark.Model.Operations.SelectingResult<TIn, TOut>.Get() in D:/a/1/s/Framework/DragonSpark/Model/Operations/SelectingResult.cs:line 23
   at async ValueTask<TOut> DragonSpark.Model.Operations.OperationResulting<TIn, TOut>.Get() in D:/a/1/s/Framework/DragonSpark/Model/Operations/OperationResulting.cs:line 30
   at async Task DragonSpark.Presentation.Components.Dialogs.DialogClassMonitor.OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender) in D:/a/1/s/Framework/DragonSpark.Presentation/Components/Dialogs/DialogClassMonitor.razor:line 39
```

It would seem that jQuery is not loaded at this moment when executing, but it is listed in the `head` of my document as the first `script` tag of my document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
    <base href="/" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest">
    <link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#2d89ef">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#b5dce8">

    <!-- CSS links (omitted) -->

    <!-- CDN-based Scripts -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/feather-icons/dist/feather.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.syncfusion.com/blazor/20.1.52/syncfusion-blazor.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- Meta/OpenGraph links -->

</head>
```

I have also tried to move my CDN script tags to the body but this does not seem to do any good, either.  The error still occurs -- albeit rarely, but still occurs.

Any guidance and/or recommendations here to address this tricky problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would strive not to use jQuery at all in a Blazor app--manipulating HTML? That's what Blazor is for!  But I guess that's your rope to risk hanging yourself with.   I agree that per the above, `$()` should always be available via interop, so I'm stumped.  Does it work to call `jQuery()`  instead?

Comment: Haha!  I am actually quite aligned with your mentality @PatrickSzalapski.  I am not a fan of jQuery and could probably do without it.  Nonetheless, my underlying concern here is that if it's happening to one CDN link, it will occur with any of them, and it would be nice to get some insight/guidance on why this occurring.

Comment: Great, thanks! So, does it work to call `jQuery()` instead of `$()`?  Just an idea; I'm guessing you'll get the same result.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @PatrickSzalapski.  I am pretty sure it will end in the same result.  The problem here is that CDN resources appear to not be loading/prepared for Blazor in some intermittent way (I have not seen this error since reporting it).  It just so happens to fail with jQuery as it is the first/most prevalent one used.

Comment: FWIW @PatrickSzalapski I did try the jQuery and ran into the same problem.  I was able to reproduce this locally and figured out a solution as seen by my answer.  Seems like a browser issue that I might report to Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this on my local machine by basically refreshing my Blazor Server-side application a bunch of times.  About one out of every 20-30 tries would produce this error.

Turns out this has nothing to do with Blazor, but it appears to be an issue with the browser.  The js file from `code.jquery.com` simply does not load despite being the first script in my `head` tag.  It does not appear in the `Sources` tab in Developer Tools.

I addressed this by doing three things:

1. Moving my CDN script tags as the very first resources in my head tag.  Prior they were after CSS files.  They are now the first.
2. Used `slim.min.js` variant seen below (this appears to be file size-related)
3. Used two tags as seen below:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Even though there are two tags in the document, the `Sources` tab only shows one.  Further, it appears that if one tag fails to load, the other takes its place.  This seems like a bug or something weird going on with Chrome.  Perhaps I will report it to Google.

Answer (score 0):

When you do a Jsinterop call from Blazor to call .js script, blazor fails to understand query selector '$' symbol. what you need to do is replace

```
$() -> document keyword
ex document.getElementById("foo")
```

from the script which is being called in that OnAfterRenderAsync.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Wajeeh.  While that is a good workaround (and something I will probably end up doing), I am more concerned about jQuery not being available to Blazor despite it being the first `script` tag in my document's `head`.  Note that the `window.$` works fine "most" of the time, but it also intermittently fails with the above, and is what I am trying to track down here.

Comment: thanks mike, please let me know when you find a proper solution to this, this is what i did when i faced a smiliar problem as a temp fix.